# Marking the text in a question (or answer)

Tags: support, markdown

Sometimes I see grayed text (for example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463464/heap-corruption-detected/5463600#5463600), the word "very" is grayed).

So, how do people do it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using backticks (`).

`Like this`

It's primarily for inline code.